# pymongo full text search how to return only stats?

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, pymongo, freetext

I am using free text search of mongo2.4 with pymongo.
What I want is to get the number of documents having some text. In the mongo shell, increasing the limit is a good turnaround, but from python it gets very slow since all documents have to be sent. For indication, the query is ~50 times slower in pymongo compared to mongo shell.

I use a command similar to this:

```
>>>res=db.command('text','mytable',search='eden',limit=100000)
>>>numfound = res['stats']['nfound']
```

But as I said, since all documents are returned, it is really slow. Is there a command to specify that you don't need documents, just the stats??
What is the list of all available options??

thx,
colin

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a server ticket for this feature - so please add a feature request to: [jira.mongodb.org](http://jira.mongodb.org) then you'll get updates and feedback from the core server developers.

You can project when doing a text query, so you can reduce the amount sent over the wire - but still sends some information eg:

```
db.mytable.runCommand( "text", { search: "eden", project: {_id: 0, b: 1}})
```

Comment: Did that answer it for you @colin?

Comment: Yes, it answered the question. thanks (i tried to vote for it but still don't have enough reputation)